# HttpsURLConnection keeps setting wrong parameters

Tags: android

I want to perform a HTTPS request, I'm doing this:

```
String myParams = "param1=ok&param2=ok";
byte[] outputInBytes = myParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("https://myurl.com/sendData.asp");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(outputInBytes.length));
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputInBytes);
os.close();

response = conn.getResponseCode();

InputStream in = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

in = conn.getInputStream();
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
    byteArrayOut.write(c);

byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOut.toByteArray();
s = new String(byteArray);
```

Although I'm doing this, while debugging the `conn` object, here is the information I get :

[image]

I don't think it's a server-side issue because I'm using the same endpoint on the iOS version of the app without any issue. So what may cause this issue?

Thank you

Comment: At which line of code was the debugger when you sampled the screen capture output?  Did you verify that you are at least hitting the endpoint in ASP when you run your code from Android?

Comment: It is quite tricky to use raw Http client, try using library like retrofit. Made my life easier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I stopped the execution at the `conn.getOutputStream()` line. I also ensured that the URL is actually the one I expect to call.

Comment: @IoaneSharvadze Thanks for your reply. That's what I usually do with iOS (I use Alamofire) but didn't learn to use any good library for Android yet. I think I'm going to do so then.

Comment: @Somday it is best library for HTTP stuff, library has excellent support and is well documented. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally use the core java http library but it seems that if you do no attempt to read the response, the request actually does not do anything.

add a `conn.getInputStream().read()` at the end and the request should be sent.

to test this I tried the following:

```
    String myParams = "param1=ok&param2=ok";
    byte[] outputInBytes = myParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    String request = "https://requestb.in/1emd86r1";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(outputInBytes.length));

    //this is needed for reqeustbin
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(outputInBytes);
    os.close();

    conn.getInputStream().read();  //without this the request was not send. with it it is send.
```

However, I do not recommend using this for making your requests. In stead you might want to try and use a lib like Apache HttpClient/OkHttp/Netty

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I didn't paste the whole chunk of code being used, but I'm actually also reading the input stream, simply didn't add it to my question as I thought it was not relevant. I'm going to add it to my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: fyi, the debugger does not seem to play nice with httpurlconnection. I successfuly do a post request with the above code but the debugger still reports "get" as the method

Comment: Ok so the problem seems to be different... Thanks for this useful information

Comment: if you want to debug further, try reading the response and checking error codes. It could be a missing user agent (some servers don't like requests without one). But once again, you might just want to use one of those libs.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use in my Android code would look fairly similar to what you have in your code snippet, but would end with the following additional code:

```
// at this point the call is actually made
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

// your response data is available in 'response'
```

This might be useful if you also plan on reading and using the response from your ASP endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I said to p.streef that's actually what I'm doing but forgot to mention it since I didn't think it was relevant..

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions.  Are you hitting your server side endpoint?  What data comes back from the call?

Comment: Yes I do, the server returns "0" which is the error response, but still a response. I actually don't work on the backend part so I'm going to ask the developer that's in charge of this part for more information about this issue.

Comment: I'm not at all certain that you are even calling properly, e.g. passing the right parameters.  I think we absolutely need to know whether you are hitting the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'm making my https requests, you can try my method and see if it will work for you.

```
 public void makeRequest(){


 try {

                    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    InputStream caInput;


                    //I have stored my C.A certificates in Resources.raw file, Get it this way
                    caInput = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.godaddysecure));



                    Certificate ca;

                    try {
                        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                        System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Certificate " + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                    } finally {
                        caInput.close();
                    }


                    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs


                    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                    keyStore.load(null, null);
                    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


                    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
                    tmf.init(keyStore);

                    Log.d("MyApp", "KeyStore Initialized ");


                    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore


                    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager


                    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
                    Log.d("MyApp", "SSL context call ");
                    URL url = new URL("Your String URl here");


                    urlConnection =
                            (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                    // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext

                    //Replace below with your own request properties
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Your Request properties here");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
                    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());


                    try {

                        //Write your output stream to server here
                        String body = "Boody of request i was sending";

                        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                        wr.write(body);

                        wr.flush();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.d("MyApp", "Body write Exception " + e.toString());
                    }


                    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();


                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();


                    //get your server response as below
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    StringBuilder bd = new StringBuilder();

                    System.out.println("Before String builder " + reader);

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println("Before String builder while loop");
                        String output = bd.append(line).toString();
                        System.out.println("Output " + output + " code " + responseCode);
                        strResponse = output;


                    }

                } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                    Log.d("Mfinance", "Login Activity Exception");
                  //  e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {

                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.d("Mfinance", "Loans Activity Exception");
                      //  e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }}
```